# In Reporting Services, increase the quality of the background image above 96 dpi

Tags: reporting-services

I'd like to use a background image, and when I put it in Reporting Services 2008 R2, the image dpi is reduced to 96 dpi. (instead of 300)

That's too low to be readable by the user, I fear.

When I go on the Internet, I find this result :

http://social.technet.microsoft.com/Forums/en-US/sqlreportingservices/thread/48de91f9-1844-40c1-9614-5ead0b4b69a5#P1Q14

> **Question 14**: How to improve PDF quality of the report exported in Reporting Services 2005?
>
> **Answer**:   The PDF renderer in Reporting Services 2005 resizes all images that it is given at 96 DPI no matter what DPI the image is when
>   you pass it to the renderer. That means that a 300 DPI image or even a
>   600 DPI image will be sized in the PDF as if it is only 96 DPI. In
>   other words, your high DPI image may render larger than expected.
>   Despite sizing the images as if they were 96 DPI, the PDF renderer
>   appears to render higher DPI images at a higher quality than 96 DPI.
>   Even if the sizing being wrong, the image actually is rendering at a
>   higher quality.   A necessary workaround is to size the image to the
>   proper number of inches based on 96 DPI calculations. Then use
>   Bitmap.SetResolution to set the  images to at least 300 DPI.  That may
>   provide a higher quality image that is the proper number of pixels to
>   fit properly in the report.

But I don't know how to use that Bitmap.SetResolution, I'm using the classic report viewer web control and I need really a fully functional pdf export.

PS : Maybe that issue is resolved in Reporting Services 2012. Does someone has some informations ?

Regards

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I found a webpage which explain how to export PDF with a good dpi. http://codeproject.com/Articles/95750/High-fidelity-printing-through-the-SSRS-Report-Vie

The key is to initialize the deviceInfo string with a xml code

```
       var sb = new System.Text.StringBuilder(1024);
       var xr = System.Xml.XmlWriter.Create(sb);
       xr.WriteStartElement("DeviceInfo");
       xr.WriteElementString("DpiX", "296");
       xr.WriteElementString("DpiY", "296");
       xr.Close();

        deviceInfo = sb.ToString();

        rsExec.SetExecutionParameters(parameters, "fr-fr");

        results = rsExec.Render(format, deviceInfo,
                  out extension, out encoding,
                  out mimeType, out warnings, out streamIDs);
```

In this case, this solution works. I can generate a pdf file with the good dpi BUT the print button with activex doesn't work (this shouldn't be a problem) and the export button either. I have to add a download button to print. that's a partial solution imho

Answer (score 1):

If you use the WebAPI interface to Reporting Services, I found this way works:

In order to get better PDF rendering of Images, pass the Device Info like this:  `http://serverName/ReportServer?/pathtoReport/ReportName&InvoiceIdOrOtherParameter=24013&rs:Command=Render&rs:Format=PDF&rs:DeviceInfo=<DpiX>300<%2FDpiX><DpiY>300<%2FDpiY>`

Answer (score 0):

The answers above led me to this, but I wanted to clarify for those using different coding platforms. The goal is to build the following string to be sent as the DeviceInfo parameter:

```
    DeviceInfo = '<DeviceInfo><DpiX>300</DpiX><DpiY>300</DpiY></DeviceInfo>'
```

By doing this, I was able to use a 300dpi image as a background image and render correctly to pdf, although you'll want to find a way to hide the image while you are designing in reportviewer as the preview still shows it much larger.