# SSRS ReportViewer - How to improve image quality when exporting to PDF

Tags: pdf, reporting-services, reportviewer

For a while now I have noticed whenever I export reports from the ReportViewer control (Webforms version) to PDF format, any included images lose quality and appear slightly pixelated.

They look just fine in the ReportViewer however.

From what I have read, the PDF renderer will size any included images at 96 dpi, no matter what dpi the image is originally.

I have done some digging and came across this post [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13764759/in-reporting-services-increase-the-quality-of-the-background-image-above-96-dpi)

I have tried this approach in my own code behind by wiring up a button like so

```
protected void btnExport_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        string mimeType, encoding, fileNameExtension;
        Warning[] warnings;
        string[] streams;

        var sb = new StringBuilder(1024);
        var xr = XmlWriter.Create(sb);
        xr.WriteStartElement("DeviceInfo");
        xr.WriteElementString("DpiX", "300");
        xr.WriteElementString("DpiY", "300");
        xr.Close();

        byte[] bytes = ReportViewer1.ServerReport.Render("PDF", sb.ToString(), out mimeType, out encoding,
                                            out fileNameExtension, out streams, out warnings);

        Response.ContentType = "application/pdf";
        Response.AppendHeader("Content-Disposition", "attachment; filename=Test.pdf");
        Response.BinaryWrite(bytes);
    }
```

This actually makes my images appear much smaller in the exported PDF compared to what shows in the Report Viewer control.

My original images are 600x600 at 300dpi, I have tried using these images as they are and on the image properties in the report RDL designer set the sizing property to 'Fit' and sizing the image to 0.25in x 0.25in. Again, all looking great in preview mode in the Report Viewer control but then quality is lost when exporting to PDF.

I tried resizing the images to 0.25in x 0.25in in my image editor (paint.net) leaving at 300 dpi, but still no difference in the results.

I'm just going round in circles now, no doubt I am missing something. I hope there is a way and someone can shed some light for me?

Thanks!

Comment: Did you ever figure this out?  I have been looking for a solution to the same issues for some time now.

Comment: Im afraid not, kinda given up and just put it down to 'by design' of how the report viewer works. Please let me know if you get any further with this!